# Add computed boolean column SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How do I add a computed boolean (`bit`) column to a SQL Server table that depends on two other boolean columns? (I'd prefer a SSMS solution).

I can get a computed column with the correct values by using the following:

```
case when ([ColumnA]=(1)) AND ([ColumnB]=(0)) then (1) else (0) end
```

but then the resulting column is type `int` which falls over when I use the data in C#

Looking around, it seems I need to use a `CAST` statement but I haven't managed to work out the syntax. I know this doesn't work:

```
cast (case when ([ColumnA]=(1)) AND ([ColumnB]=(0)) then (1) else (0) end) as bit
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You `misplaced` the `parenthesis`. try this.

```
      Cast (CASE
               WHEN  [ColumnA] =  1  
                    AND  [ColumnB] =  0   THEN  1 
               ELSE  0 
             END AS BIT)
```

Comment: Wow, I thought only the case ... end was bracketed.  Many thanks.